# How to pass string in objective-c instance method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, methods

Hi I have multiple UIButtons (`foo` and `bar`) and when pressed each invokes a different instance method (`doSomethingFoo` and `doSomethingBar`). Here is the code I have working:

```
CGRect fooImageRect = CGRectMake(38.0f, 192.0f, 130.0f, 25.0f);
    UIButton *buttonFoo = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    buttonFoo.frame = fooImageRect;
    [buttonFoo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_foo_130x25.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonFoo addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomethingFoo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonFoo];
    [buttonFoo release];

CGRect barImageRect = CGRectMake(172.0f, 192.0f, 130.0f, 25.0f);
    UIButton *buttonBar = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    buttonBar.frame = barImageRect;
    [buttonBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_bar_130x25.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonBar addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomethingBar:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonBar];
    [buttonBar release];
```

And the instance methods `doSomethingFoo` and `doSomethingBar`

```
    -(void)doSomethingFoo:(id) sender {
    // code doing something with a NSString having value 'foo'
}

     -(void)doSomethingBar:(id) sender {
        // same code doing something with a NSString having value 'bar'
}
```

What I am trying to do is to create a single method (`doSomething`) that I can invoke when either button is pressed, and pass it the string (value 'foo' or 'bar') that I'll reference in the method.  I'm struggling with the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same method to handle both buttons, but you cannot choose the arguments that get sent.  The action selector must be one of the following forms:

```
- (void)action
- (void)action:(id)sender
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Where `sender` is the control that sent the message.  So you'll be able to tell which of the two buttons sent the message by checking the `sender`.  On possibility to make the check straight-forward would be to to set the tag property of the UIButton when you create it with some well known value (a #define or some other constant) and check that property in your action method.

Answer (score 0):

simply make an NSString ivar called buttonTitle and write the method like so:

```
// first set buttonTitle:
self.buttonTitle = @"foo"; //for buttonfoo
self.buttonTitle = @"bar",  // for buttonbar




-(void)doSomething:(id) sender {
 NSString *title = self.buttonTitle;
}
```